# Select Index not working as expected

Tags: javascript

DOM:

```
<select name="statusId">
  <option value="">Choose a status</option>
  <option value="12856801">Not a Fit</option>
  <option value="12882961">Contacted </option>
  <option value="13071711">No Contact Info</option>
```

I found this code and tried it:

```
var textToFind = 'Contacted';
var dd = document.getElementsByName('statusId')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
    if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
        dd.selectIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

It's not setting the value, it's just returning `2`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The property name is `selectedIndex` ...

Answer (score 1):

`selectedIndex` not `selectIndex`

I can't read.